# Docx no importa "WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH"

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx

tengo un simple script cuya función es crear un documento de word, la terminal me arroja: **AttributeError: '_Footer' object has no attribute 'paragraph_format'**, copié el import directamente de un turorial pero Vscode no lo reconoce. Aquí dejó el código para que puedan reproducirlo.

```
import mysql.connector
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE
from docx.shared import Pt
from docx.shared import Inches
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH


# Establecer la conexión con la base de datos MySQL
conn= conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="Baelca1", database="Lista_datos_Baelca")
cursor1=conn.cursor()

# Ejecutar una consulta SQL y almacenar los resultados en una variable
cursor1.execute("SELECT * FROM ticket")
results=cursor1.fetchall()

# Crear un nuevo documento de Word
document = Document()


# Crear un nuevo estilo de párrafo personalizado
style = document.styles.add_style('CustomFont', WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH)

# Establecer la fuente y el tamaño de los caracteres en el estilo
style.font.name = 'Arial'
style.font.size = Pt(12)

# Agregar un título al documento
document.add_heading('Título del documento', 0)

# Obtener la primera sección del documento
section = document.add_section()
section.page_width = Inches(8.5)
section.page_height = Inches(11)
section.top_margin = Inches(0.75)
section.bottom_margin = Inches(0.75)
section.left_margin = Inches(0.75)
# Define margins
section.right_margin = Inches(0.75)

# Agregar el membrete
header = section.header
header.add_paragraph('Membrete de la empresa')

# Recorrer los resultados de la consulta y agregar cada fila al documento
for row in results:
    for element in row:
        document.add_paragraph(str(element))
    document.add_paragraph('')

# Agregar la fecha a pie de página
footer = section.footer
footer.add_paragraph('Fecha: ', style='Footer')
footer.paragraph_format.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.RIGHT

# Guardar el documento
document.save("document.docx")
```

No veo que haya nada mal en la sintaxis, simplemente el import no reconoce "WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ese [alias](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/enum/WdAlignParagraph.html) no funciona por algún motivo que desconozco.

Prueba usando el nombre real del enum, `WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT`

```
from docx.enum.text import WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT
```

Y usa `WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT` en todos los lugares donde estés usando `WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH`.

Comment: Gracias hermano, lo reconoció. El problema es que ahora la terminal me arroja ** AttributeError: '_Footer' object has no attribute 'paragraph_format'** cosa que no me decía antes.

Comment: Según está redactada tu pregunta ese siempre fue el error xD